# Call Current Category

Tags: categories, php

I'm using this in a file named category-portfolio.php which is for the archives page of my portfolio.  I don't want to use cat= to specify a specific category.  But when I don't use cat= it pulls up every post regardless of category.  How do I make this code pull up only the current/relevant/portfolio category?  Thanks a million!

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="container">
<div id="portfolio_content">

<!-- Grab posts -->
<?php
query_posts('posts_per_page=9&paged='.$paged); 
if (have_posts()) :
?>

<div id="portfolio_wrap">
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>  

<!-- Get the image -->
<div class="img">
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">


<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail( 'thmb-portfolio' ); } ?>

<!-- Excerpt title -->
<span class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></span></a>

<!-- Excerpt description -->
<div class="desc"><?php my_excerpt('short'); ?></div>

</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<!-- Next/Previous Posts -->
<?php if (function_exists("pagination")) {
    pagination($additional_loop->max_num_pages);
} ?>

</div>

<!-- #portfolio_wrap -->
<?php endif; ?>

</div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your call to query_posts is overwriting the original query for the page. You have to get the original query, then modify any params from there.

```
global $query_string;
// start with the original query
$myquery = wp_parse_args($query_string);
// make any changes to the query here
$myquery['posts_per_page'] = 9;
query_posts($myquery);
```